# What is this moth-like insect that come through my window screen?

Tags: windows, insect

[image]

Here is a picture. I see a lot of insects like these near my window. Anyone has ideas about what species are they and how to avoid attracting them? Thanks!

Comment: Those look like ants or termites  not moths I can’t tell can you get a closer photo.

Comment: Your screen appears to need repair. I would guess these are coming in through the gap visible at the bottom of the screen, not through the screen itself. @EdBeal - it's a bigger picture than SE shows - open it in a new window and zoom in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened the photo again and I am leaning to a termite swarm. Wings look thicker and even, I can’t quite see the antenna but they don’t look like ants and although the body looks thicker than an ant I am not a pro but have remodeled both termite and carpenter ant / flying ants houses in Oregon. And the heavy wings straight thick body to me remind me of those wood munching home wreckers. So I would suggest that, killing them with spray would be a good thing, if a swarm they may have come from someplace else and resting up looking for a new home. If you can spray some and get a couple bodies if the antennas can be zoomed in on and the body maybe we could tell with confidence.

Comment: Yeah, I searched some pictures online. Those are very likely to be termites to me. Thanks for the help!